# open shift rhc setup in windows(no ssh key found error)

Tags: openshift, git-bash, openshift-client-tools

[image]My system already have ssh key,Then how set this ssh key to my open shift application.Any other way available to run rhc setup?

Answer (score 0):

Did you get an error? It looks like you just need to finish running rhc setup.  Accept the default server and keep going.

Comment: how to set default server in rhc setup?

Comment: You just accept the default server when it is shown. (openshift.redhat.com)